# Message: "View [test] not found." trace: [{file: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php"

Tags: angular, laravel

I developed a web Application using Laravel-5.8 as backend and Angular-7 as frontend. The Application sends mail using Gmail.

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER = smtp
MAIL_HOST = smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT = 465
MAIL_USERNAME = james@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = ssl
```

When I tested it locally, was working fine. But when I deployed to the server, mails are not being send, but I got this error:

> Message: "View [test] not found." trace: [{file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php"

Initially, it was going but suddenly this error just occurred. I redeployed but the problem is still there.

But locally, everything is fine.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: try `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Do you have a views folder in storage/framework?

Comment: @RahulRai - Yes, I have views folder kin storage/framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `/resources/views` folder to see if there's a file called `test.blade.php`. If it exists, clear cache with `php artisan view:clear` and try performing the action again.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Comment: The problem still persists

Comment: If Your Blade Exists                                                                                                                                                                        
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan view:clear 
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache